# KOTLIN - textToSpeech repeat

Tags: android, loops, kotlin, text-to-speech

I was wondering if it is possible that once I turn text to speech on, that text to speech constantly reads the value

```
currentItem.percent
```

this value is constantly updated so I want each new value to be read aloud

```
 tts = TextToSpeech(Context, TextToSpeech.OnInitListener { status ->

                    if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) // if no error set language
                        tts.language = Locale.UK


                    tts.speak(
                        currentItem.percent.toString(),
                        TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD,
                        null,
                        ""
                    );

                    tts.speak(
                        currentItem.percent.toString(),
                        TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD,
                        null,
                        ""
                    );
```

the code above just reads the same percent value twice? any ideas on how to fix this?

**edit**

I've also tried this loop with no luck, The app doesn't read in a new value and continues to say the same value each time

```
    for (i in 0..6) {
tts.speak(
currentItem.percent.toString(),
TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD,
 null,
""
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're hearing the same value repeated is because the `speak` method doesn't wait until the speech synthesis is complete before returning. From the docs:

> This method is asynchronous, i.e. the method just adds the request to the queue of TTS requests and then returns. The synthesis might not have finished (or even started!) at the time when this method returns.
>
> ([Android developer docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech#speak(java.lang.CharSequence,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle,%20java.lang.String)))

That means that when you call `speak` several times repeatedly, you're really just adding the same value to the queue several times.

Instead, what you need to do is introduce a short delay each time you call `speak`. One way to do that is to use a `Handler` in your activity.

```kotlin
private val handler = Handler()
```

Then make a method which will both read the current value and queue up a new task to read it again later:

```kotlin
val delayMs = 2000

fun speakCurrentValue() {
    tts.speak(
        currentItem.percent.toString(),
        TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD,
        null,
        ""
    )
    handler.postDelayed(Runnable { speakCurrentValue() }, delayMs)
}
```

Now, after you call `speakCurrentValue`, it will keep queuing itself up to be run again later.

Comment: if this is within a fragment is the code the same?

Comment: Yes, you can create the Handler inside a fragment instead 

Comment: ive tried this code again, when adding the handler im presented with the error property setter or getter expected, what should i do here